# Adjective before or after noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I received a name card from a client that reads as below:

> "Senior Sea Export Customer Service Executive"

Kindly advise if there's any mistake on it because it just doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You just encountered something called an **[attributive noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun)**.

I don't see a big problem with the string given. Something like...

> Senior Executive 
>  Senior Customer Service Executive 
>  Senior Sea Export Customer Service Executive

---

However, I'd have preferred this in a name card

> Sophia K 
>  
>   Senior Customer Service Executive, 
>  Sea Export (Ltd or whatever...)

Comment: Sea Export Department/Division, FredBloogs Co Ltd - perhaps. I'm assuming they have customer service reps (CSRs) for many departments/divisions - hopefully not all with such important-sounding titles ;)